# Comparing one row with next row in Python dataframe

Tags: python, parsing, compare, dataframe

I want to compare a row with its next row in a python data frame, then do some addition if they are the same. But, the codes I wrote are not working.

My play dataframe head is below.

```
          GameCode  PlayNumber  PeriodNumber  Clock  OffenseTeamCode  \
0  299004720130829           1             1    900               47   
1  299004720130829           2             1    NaN              299   
2  299004720130829           3             1    NaN              299   
3  299004720130829           4             1    NaN              299   
4  299004720130829           5             1    NaN              299   

   DefenseTeamCode  OffensePoints  DefensePoints  Down  Distance  Spot  \
0              299              0              0   NaN       NaN    65   
1               47              0              0     1        10    75   
2               47              0              0     2         7    72   
3               47              0              0     3         1    66   
4               47              0              0     1        10    64   

  PlayType  DriveNumber  DrivePlay  
0  KICKOFF          NaN        NaN  
1     RUSH            1          1  
2     PASS            1          1  
3     RUSH            1          1  
4     RUSH            1          1
```

I want to compare the gamecode in first row and it matches with the second row, do some operation of adding them and so. But I'm getting an error in the following code.

```
print play.head()
df = pd.DataFrame()

rushingyards = 0
passingyards = 0

for row in play.itertuples():
    if df.empty:
        df = play
    else:
        if play['GameCode'] == df['GameCode']:
            if play['PlayType'] in ('RUSH','PASS'):
                if play['PlayType']=='RUSH':
                    rushingyards = rushingyards+play['Distance']
                else:
                    passingyards  = passingyards + play['Distance']
```

Kindly help.

Comment: One thing I see that might be a problem is that you're not specifying the row. Try df.ix or df.iloc to put the row into play in your comparisons and see if that fixes your problem. Ix may be particularly helpful because you just need a row number and a column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are lookng for a groupby/sum operation:

```
yards = df.groupby(['GameCode', 'PlayType'])['Distance'].sum().unstack('PlayType')
# PlayType         KICKOFF  PASS  RUSH
# GameCode                            
# 299004720130829      NaN     7    21
```

For each `GameCode` and `PlayType`, this sums the `Distance`s. The `unstack` returns a DataFrame with an index of `GameCode`s and columns of `PlayType`s.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
nan = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Clock': [900.0, nan, nan, nan, nan],
     'DefensePoints': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     'DefenseTeamCode': [299, 47, 47, 47, 47],
     'Distance': [nan, 10.0, 7.0, 1.0, 10.0],
     'Down': [nan, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0],
     'DriveNumber': [nan, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
     'DrivePlay': [nan, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
     'GameCode': [299004720130829, 299004720130829, 299004720130829,
                  299004720130829, 299004720130829],
     'OffensePoints': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     'OffenseTeamCode': [47, 299, 299, 299, 299],
     'PeriodNumber': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     'PlayNumber': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     'PlayType': ['KICKOFF', 'RUSH', 'PASS', 'RUSH', 'RUSH'],
     'Spot': [65, 75, 72, 66, 64]})

yards = df.groupby(['GameCode', 'PlayType'])['Distance'].sum().unstack('PlayType')
passing_yards, rushing_yards = yards['PASS'], yards['RUSH']
```

Note `passing_yards` and `rushing_yards` will be Series, with an index of `GameCodes`.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Is there a way to combine passing and rushing yards with a single gameCode ? Like, Gamecode, Passingyard,rushingyards all in a table. with no duplication of gamecode. ?

Comment: Can you help with the above scenario ? @unutbu

Comment: Can you post the desired result? I'm not sure if you want to sum the passing yards with the rushing yards: `yards['PASS'] + yards['RUSH']` or if you want to drop the `KICKOFF` column: `yards.drop('KICKOFF', axis=1)`, or something else...

Comment: Or perhaps you want to sum the passing and rushing yards for a specific GameCode, as in `yards.loc[299004720130829, 'PASS'] + yards.loc[299004720130829, 'RUSH']`. But note that you usually should not want to deal with single GameCodes -- you get better performance out of Pandas (as well as more elegant-looking code) if you can use Pandas methods to calculate what you want for all the GameCodes at once.

Comment: I want a result like the following. 

    Gamecode                    rushing_yards              passingyards
    299004720130829                   893                             401
    299004720130824                   450                             657
    299004720130821                   430                             357

I want a table like this, so that I can use that for analysis.